# Prove that $\frac{\tan x}{x}>\frac{x}{\sin x}, x\in(0,\pi/2)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, derivatives, inequality

> Prove that $$\frac{\tan x}{x}>\frac{x}{\sin x},\;\;\; x\in(0,\pi/2).$$

**My work**

I formulated $$f(x)=\tan x \sin x - x^2$$ in hope that if $f'(x)>0$ i.e. monotonic then I can conclude for $x>0, f(x)>f(0)$ and hence, prove the statement.

However, I got $$f'(x)=\sin x + \sec x \tan x -2x, $$ where I am unable to conclude if $f'(x)>0.$

I also found $$f''(x)=\cos x + 2\sec^3x-\sec x-2,$$

$$f'''(x)=-\sin x (1-6\sec^4x+\sec^2x).$$

But I am not able conclude the sign of any of the higher derivatives either. Am I doing something wrong? Or is there some other way?

Comment: You could try to show that $\frac{\tan x \sin x}{x^2} > 1$. At $x = 0$, using the limit of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$, you see that the LHS is 1 (in the limit). Can you show it's greater than $1$ for $x > 0$? (If you know Taylor series, this is a lot easier...)

Comment: You can see that $f'''$ is positive because $(1+t-6t^{2})=(1+3t)(1-2t)<0$ if $t>1/2$ or if $t<-1/3$. Now $t=\sec^{2}x\geq 1$ so we are done.

Comment: @JohnHughes. This is the beauty of the Taylor expansion of $\tan(x)\sin(x)$.

Comment: See related question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1052492/72031

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that by denoting $f(x) = \tan x \sin x -x^2$, you found that $$f'''(x)=-\sin x (1-6\sec^4x+\sec^2x) = \sin x (1+3\sec^2 x)(2\sec^2 x -1 ) \geq 0 $$
Hence $f''(x)$ is increasing, with $f''(0)=0$, we conclude that $f''(x) \geq 0$.

Hence $f'(x)$ is increasing, with $f'(0)=0$, we conclude that $f'(x) \geq 0$.

Hence $f(x)$ is increasing, with $f(0)=0$, we conclude that $f(x) \geq 0$.

This is what we wish to prove.

---

From a more advanced perspective, the inequality follows from the fact that Taylor expansion of $$\tan x \sin x = x^2+\frac{x^4}{6}+\cdots$$ at $x=0$ have all coefficients positive, the radius of convergence of this series is $\pi/2$.

To see why all coefficients are positive, write
$$\tan x \sin x = \frac{1}{\cos x} - \cos x$$

The Taylor expansion of $\sec x$ at $x=0$ is $$\sec x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n E_{2n}}{(2n)!} x^{2n}$$
where $E_{2n}$ are [Euler number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number). The fact that $(-1)^n E_{2n}$ is positive follows from the series evaluation:
$$\beta(2n+1) = \frac{(-1)^n E_{2n} \pi^{2n+1}}{4^{2n+1} (2n)!}$$
with $\beta(n)$ the [Dirichlet beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function).

Also note that we have $|E_{2n}| > 1 $ when $n>1$, hence the power series of $\frac{1}{\cos x}-\cos x$ has all coefficients positive.

---

From this, you might want to prove the stronger inequality:

> When $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$, 
>   $$\tan x \sin x > x^2 + \frac{x^4}{6} $$
>   $$\tan x \sin x > x^2 + \frac{x^4}{6} + \frac{31x^6}{360} $$

Comment: If $f'(x)\ge 0$, then $f(x)$ is non-decreasing, not strictly increasing.

Comment: But it depends on how you define "increasing".

Comment: Why we need to check $f'''$ and $f''$? Don't we only need to check $f'$?

Answer (score 8):

I believe the simplest proof is through the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$$\tan(x)\sin(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{d\theta}{\cos^2\theta}\int_{0}^{x}\cos(\theta)\,d\theta\geq\left(\int_{0}^{x}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\cos\theta}}\right)^2\geq\left(\int_{0}^{x}d\theta\right)^2=x^2. $$
In a similar fashion, for any $x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ we have  $\frac{\tan x }{x}\geq\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^2$ by Holder's inequality.

Comment: I'm not aware about Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in integral form but it seems really clear in this way. I've just tried a proof using bounding value from Taylor's series.

Answer (score 5):

We need to prove that
$$\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos{x}}>x^2$$ or $f(x)>0$, where
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin{x}}{\sqrt{\cos{x}}}-x.$$
Now, let $\cos{x}=t^2$, where $0<t<1$.

Thus, $$f'(x)=\frac{1+\cos^2x}{2\sqrt{\cos^3x}}-1=\frac{(1-t)(1+t+t^2-t^3)}{2t^3}>0,$$ which says $f(x)>f(0)=0$ and  we are done!

Comment: Very ingenious to take square root! +1

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

$$\tan x \sin x>\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3}\right)\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}\right)=x^2+\frac{x^4}{6}-\frac{x^6}{18}>x^2\iff3-x^2>0\iff x < \sqrt 3$$

Answer (score 1):

We can prove a stronger inequality 
$$\frac{\tan x}{x} > \left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^2$$ for $x \in (0, \pi/2)$. Indeed the function 
$\tan x \sin^2 x - x^3$ has derivative $\tan^2 x + 2 \sin^2 x - 3 x^2$. Now, from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2391978/is-there-a-geometrical-method-to-prove-x-frac-sin-x-tan-x2/2392895#2392895) we see that $\frac{\tan x + 2 \sin x }{3} > x$ for $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ so 
$\frac{\tan^2 x + 2 \sin^2 x}{3}> \left(\frac{ \tan x + 2 \sin x }{3}\right)^2 > x^2$ and  we are done.

Note that the Taylor series of $1-\frac{x^3}{\tan x \sin^2 x}$ has all coefficients positive
$$1-\frac{x^3}{\tan x \sin^2 x}=\frac{x^4}{15} + \frac{4 x^6}{189} + \frac{x^8}{225}+\cdots$$

We will prove a weaker stamement than the above (which was only checked for some coefficients) by proving that the function 
$$f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{\cos^{\frac{1}{3}} x}$$ has the Taylor series at $0$ with all coefficients positive. For this, we notice that 
$$f^{(2)}(x) =\frac{4}{9} \frac{\sin^3 x}{\cos^{\frac{7}{3}}x} =\frac{4}{9} \sec^{\frac{4}{3}}x \cdot f^3(x)$$

Now, $\sec x$ at any positive power has all Taylor coefficients positive. This follows from the fact that $\sec x$ has a product expansion with factors $\frac{1}{1- a_k x^2}$ and the series $(1-t)^{-\alpha}$ has all Taylor coefficients positive. Now, the fact that $f$ has all coefficients positive follows by induction, by using the recurrence given by the differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{x}{2} < \tan \frac{x}{2}$ for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have for such $x$-values:
$$ \left( \frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2 > \left( \frac{2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}} {2 \tan \frac{x}{2}}\right)^2 = \left(\cos \frac{x}{2} \right)^4 = \frac14 \left(1+\cos x\right)^2 > \cos x $$
using that the difference between the two last expressions is 
$\frac14 (1-\cos x)^2>0$. The result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion using a short Taylor expansion and checking the residual.

Rewriting the inequality, we only need to show

$$\tan{x} \sin{x} \gt x^2 \mbox{ on } x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$$

Now, let's rewrite the left side (you don't need it but I like it) and give it a name $f$;
$$\tan{x} \sin{x} = \frac{\sin^2{x}}{\cos{x}} =  \frac{1-\cos^2{x}}{\cos{x}} = \frac{1}{\cos{x}} - \cos{x} = f(x)$$

$f$ can be rewritten using the Taylor polynomial around $0$ of degree $2$. 
With $f(0) = 0$, $f^{\prime}(0)=0$, $f^{\prime\prime}(0)=2$ we get

$$f(x) = x^2 + \frac{f^{(3)}(\theta_x)}{3!}x^3 \mbox{ with } \theta_x \in (0,x)$$

So, let's check the residual on the given interval:

$$f^{(3)}(x) = \frac{\sin{x}}{\cos^4{x}}(5+\sin^2{x}-\cos^4{x}) \gt 0 \mbox{ for } x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$$

Thus,

$$\frac{1}{\cos{x}} - \cos{x} = f(x) \gt x^2  \mbox{ for } x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$$

Done.

Answer (score 0):

It is known (see p. 55, Item 1.518 in the monograph [1] below) that
\begin{equation*}
\ln\sin x=\ln x+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2^{2k-1}}{k}\bigl[(-1)^kB_{2k}\bigr]\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}, \quad 0<x<\pi,
\end{equation*}
where $B_k$ denotes the Bernoulli numbers and $(-1)^kB_{2k}<0$ for all $k\ge1$. Then
\begin{equation*}
\ln x-\ln\sin x=\ln\frac{x}{\sin x}=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2^{2k-1}}{k}\bigl[(-1)^kB_{2k}\bigr]\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}>0, \quad 0<x<\pi
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
(\ln x-\ln\sin x)^{(n)}=\biggl(\ln\frac{x}{\sin x}\biggr)^{(n)}
=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2^{2k-1}}{k}\bigl[(-1)^kB_{2k}\bigr]\langle2k\rangle_n \frac{x^{2k-n}}{(2k)!}>0, \quad 0<x<\pi.
\end{equation*}
This means that the function $\ln x-\ln\sin x$ is absolutely monotonic functions on $(0,\pi)$. In other words, the even function
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x}{\sin x}, & x\ne0\\
1, & x=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
is logarithmically absolutely monotonic on $(0,\pi)$. Therefore, the function $f(x)$ is absolutely monotonic on $(0,\pi)$. Thus, we acquire $f^{(k)}(0)\ge0$ for all $k\ge0$. Accordingly, the function
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\sin x}
=\frac1x\biggl(1-\frac{x}{\sin x}\biggr)
=-\frac1x\sum_{k=1}^\infty f^{(k)}(0)\frac{x^k}{k!}
=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k+1)}(0)}{(k+1)!}x^{k}
<0
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\biggl(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\sin x}\biggr)'
=-\frac1{x^2}+\frac{1}{\tan x\sin x}
=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{kf^{(k+1)}(0)}{(k+1)!}x^{k-1}
<0
\end{equation*}
for $x\in(0,\pi)$. Consequently, we arrive at
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{\tan x\sin x}<\frac1{x^2}, \quad x\in(0,\pi),
\end{equation*}
which can be rearranged as
\begin{equation*}
\frac{x}{\sin x}<\frac{\tan x}{x}, \quad x\in\biggl(0,\frac{\pi}2\biggr).
\end{equation*}
When $x\in\bigl(\frac{\pi}2,\pi\bigr)$, the last inequality is reversed.

References

1. I. S. Gradshteyn and I. M. Ryzhik, *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products*, Translated from the Russian, Translation edited and with a preface by Daniel Zwillinger and Victor Moll, Eighth edition, Revised from the seventh edition, Elsevier/Academic Press, Amsterdam, 2015; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-384933-5.00013-8.
2. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *A property of logarithmically absolutely monotonic functions and the logarithmically complete monotonicity of a power-exponential function*, University Politehnica of Bucharest Scientific Bulletin Series A---Applied Mathematics and Physics **72** (2010), no. 2, 21--30.
3. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *Some inequalities and absolute monotonicity for modified Bessel functions of the first kind*, Communications of the Korean Mathematical Society **31** (2016), no. 2, 355--363; available online at https://doi.org/10.4134/CKMS.2016.31.2.355.
4. Feng Qi, Bai-Ni Guo, Senlin Guo, and Shou-Xin Chen, *A function involving gamma function and having logarithmically absolute convexity*, Integral Transforms and Special Functions **18** (2007), no. 11, 837--843; available online at https://doi.org/10.1080/10652460701528875.
5. Feng Qi and Peter Taylor, *Several series expansions for real powers and several formulas for partial Bell polynomials of sinc and sinhc functions in terms of central factorial and Stirling numbers of second kind*, arXiv preprint (2022), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.05612v4 or https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2204.05612.