# Maclaurin series of $1-\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right) ^{\frac{2}{5}}$ has all coefficients positive

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I had a similar [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4443400/maclaurin-series-of-1-cos2-3-x-has-all-coefficients-positive) posted here, and after  experimentation with [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=TaylorSeries%5B%20%28Sin%5Bx%5D%2Fx%29%5E%282%2F5%29%2C%20%7Bx%2C0%2C%2010%7D%5D) I noticed that the function $1-\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right) ^{\frac{2}{5}}$ has a Maclaurin expansion with all coefficients positive.

It seems to hold. A possible approach might using the product expansion for the function $\sin x$. Or maybe a differential equation.

Thank you for your interest!

$\bf{Added:}$ Denote the expression by $y(x)$. It's enough to show that $z\colon=y'$ has a positive expansion.  We [have](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%20D%5B%20%28Sin%5Bx%5D%2Fx%29%5E%282%2F5%29%2C%20%7Bx%2C%202%7D%5D%2F%20D%5B%20%28Sin%5Bx%5D%2Fx%29%5E%282%2F5%29%2C%20%7Bx%2C%201%7D%5D-%20%28%20x%5E2%2F%281-%20x%20Cot%5Bx%5D%29%20%2B%203%2F5%20%28%201%20-%20x%20Cot%5Bx%5D%29%20-2%29)
$$x\cdot  z' =  \left(\frac{x^2}{1 - x \cot x} + \frac{3}{5}( 1- x \cot x) - 2 \right)\cdot z$$

If the expression in the brackets has a positive [expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%20TaylorSeries%5Bx%5E2%2F%281-%20x%20Cot%5Bx%5D%29%20%2B%203%2F5%20%28%201%20-%20x%20Cot%5Bx%5D%29%20-2%2C%20%7Bx%2C%200%2C%2020%7D%5D) (it seems so) then we can show that $z$ has a positive expasion.

Comment: Hi stranger ! I tried with the product expansion but I am stuck. So, my answer. Cheers :-)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici:  Hello there! I am glad it attracted your interest :-)

Comment: You made two very interesting problems. I thank you for that. I had fun. Cheers :-)

Comment: Nit-pick: positive → non-negative.

Comment: If we write $1 - \left( {\frac{{\sin x}}{x}} \right)^{2/5}  = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty  {a_n x^{2n} }$, then, by singularity analysis, $$
a_n  \sim \frac{{2^{3/5} }}{{5 \cdot \Gamma (3/5)}}\frac{1}{{\pi ^{2n} n^{7/5} }}
$$ as $n\to +\infty$. This shows that the coefficients are positive at least for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: @Gary: Very interesting! Would it also mean that for any $0 < a < 1$ the coefficients of  $1- (\frac{\sin x}{x})^a$ are positive for sufficiently large $n$ ?

Comment: @orangeskid Indeed, in that case the asymptotics of the $n$th coefficient is $$
 - \frac{2}{{\Gamma ( - a)}}\frac{1}{{\pi ^{2n} n^{a + 1} }}
$$ and $\Gamma(-a)$ is negative if $0<a<1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an answer, but here's my attempt: the function $f(x) = 1 - \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{2/5}$ satisfies a differential equation
$$
\frac{y'}{1-y} = -\frac{2}{5x}(x\cot x - 1)
$$
so the coefficients of the series $f(x) = 1 + \sum_{k\geq 1} a_{2k}x^{2k}$ ($f$ is an even function) satisfy the recurrence relation
$$
2na_{2n} = \frac{2}{5}\left(b_{2n} - a_{2}b_{2n-2} - a_{4}b_{2n-4} - \cdots - a_{2n-2}b_{2} \right)
$$
where
$$
b_{2k} = \frac{(-1)^{k+1}B_{2k}2^{2k}}{(2k)!}
$$
and $B_{2k}$ is Bernoulli number. Note that $b_{2k} > 0$ for all $k\geq 1$. *Assume that the following inequality holds for all $n\geq 2$*:
$$
\sum_{1\leq k \leq n-1} \frac{1}{5k}b_{k}b_{n-k} \leq b_{n}
$$
then one can prove $0\leq a_{n} \leq \frac{b_{2n}}{5n}$ for all $n$, by induction on $n$. However, I failed to prove the above inequaltiy, and I don't even know whether the inequality is true or not. I tried to use an identity
$$
\sum_{1\leq k \leq n} b_{k}b_{n-k} = (2n+1)b_{n}
$$
(for $n\geq 2$) which comes from
$$
\coth x = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{2^{2n}B_{2n}x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}
$$
and $\frac{d}{dx}\coth x = 1 - \coth^{2}x$, but failed.

Comment: Very interesting!  I thought of proving that  the derivative $f'$ has a positive expansion. There is a [connection](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5B+%28Sin%5Bx%5D%2Fx%29%5E%282%2F5%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+2%7D%5D%2F+D%5B+%28Sin%5Bx%5D%2Fx%29%5E%282%2F5%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+1%7D%5D)  between $f''$ and $f'$ and the ratio has again a positive [expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=TaylorSeries%5B+-7%2F%285+x%29+%2B+x%2F%281+-+x+cot%28x%29%29+-+%283+cot%28x%29%29%2F5%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+20%7D%5D) ---maybe that can be also shown in a simpler way using Bernoulli numbers

Comment: $b_{2k}  = \frac{{2\zeta (2k)}}{{\pi ^{2k} }}$ and the inequality in question is equivalent to $$
\frac{2}{5}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{{\zeta (2k)\zeta (2n - 2n)}}{k}}  \le \zeta (2n).
$$ Based on numerics, this seems to fail for $n\geq 3$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the same approach as earlier
$$1-\left(\frac{\sin (x)}{x}\right)^a= \frac{a x^2}{6}\Bigg[1+\frac 1{60} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{P_n(a)}{b_n }x^{2n}\Bigg]$$ where the first $b_n$ are
$$\{1,126,15120,997920,16345929600,\cdots\}$$ and the first $P_n(a)$ are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n(a) \\
 1 & 5 a-2 \\
 2 & 35 a^2-42 a+16 \\
 3 & (5 a-4) \left(35 a^2-56 a+36\right) \\
 4 & 385 a^4-1540 a^3+2684 a^2-2288 a+768 \\
 5 & 175175 a^5-1051050 a^4+2862860 a^3-4252248 a^2+3327584 a-1061376
\end{array}
\right)$$

and all coefficients are positive as long as $a \leq \frac 25$

Comment: So how do you conclude that all $P_n(a)\geqslant 0$ ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution to the problem, by proving that the Maclaurin series of
$$\frac{x^2}{1- x \cot x} + \frac{3}{5}(1- x \cot x) - 2$$
has all coefficients positive.

Now,  from the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4447783/maclaurin-series-of-fracx21-x-cot-x/4449466#4449466) of @Gary: we found out that there is the expansion
$$\frac{x^2}{1- x \cot x} = 3 - \frac{1}{5} x^2 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n 3 \cdot 2^n V_{2n}}{(2n)!} x^{2n}$$
where $V_n$ are the van der Pol numbers. Moreover we have the inequality
$$|V_{2n}|< \frac{4 (2n)!}{15 (2\pi)^{2n}}$$

(See : Howard -- van der Pol numbers and polynomials).

Moreover, we have the expansion

$$1 - x \cot x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} 2^{2n} B_{2n}} {(2n)!} x^{2n} $$

Now I think we are able to prove that the series for the above expression has all of the coefficients positive. Details to follow.

Answer (score 0):

In the arXiv preprint [1] below, the following series expansions were established.

When $r\ge0$, the series expansions
\begin{equation}\label{recip-sin-ser-closed-eq} 
\biggl(\frac{\sin z}z\biggr)^r=1+\sum_{q=1}^{\infty}(-1)^q\Biggl[\sum_{k=1}^{2q}\frac{(-r)_k}{k!} \sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j} \frac{T(2q+j,j)}{\binom{2q+j}{j}}\Biggr]\frac{(2z)^{2q}}{(2q)!} 
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\label{recip-sin-stirl-closed-eq} 
\biggl(\frac{\sin z}z\biggr)^r=1+\sum_{q=1}^{\infty}(-1)^q\Biggl[\sum_{k=1}^{2q}\frac{(-r)_k}{k!} \sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j} \sum_{m=0}^{2q}(-1)^{m}\binom{2q}{m} \biggl(\frac{j}{2}\biggr)^{m} \frac{S(2q+j-m,j)} {\binom{2q+j-m}{j}}\Biggr]\frac{(2z)^{2q}}{(2q)!} 
\end{equation}
are convergent in $z\in\mathbb{C}$, where $T(n,k)$ and $S(n,k)$ denote the central factorial numbers and the Stirling numbers of the second kinds, and the rising factorial $(r)_k$ is defined by
\begin{equation*}%\label{rising-Factorial} 
(r)_k=\prod_{\ell=0}^{k-1}(r+\ell)
= \begin{cases} r(r+1)\dotsm(r+k-1), & k\ge1;\\ 1, & k=0. \end{cases} \end{equation*}
When $r<0$, the above two series expansions are convergent in $|z|<\pi$.

However, by virtue of these two series expansions applied to $r=\frac25$, it is very difficult to verify that the function $1-\bigl(\frac{\sin z}z\bigr)^{2/5}$ has a Maclaurin expansion with all coefficients positive.

Reference

1. F. Qi and P. Taylor, *Several series expansions for real powers and several formulas for partial Bell polynomials of sinc and sinhc functions in terms of central factorial and Stirling numbers of second kind*, arXiv (2022), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.05612v4 or https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2204.05612.