# Maclaurin series of $\frac{x^2}{1- x \cot x}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

I wonder if there is an explicit formula for the Maclaurin [expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=TaylorSeries%5B%20x%5E2%2F%281-%20x%20Cot%5Bx%5D%29%2C%20%7Bx%2C%200%2C%2020%7D%5D) of $\frac{x^2}{1 - x \cot x}$. We know an explicit [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Power_series_expansion) for $1- x \cot x$.

Due to the [continued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Continued_fraction_expansion) fraction formula for $\tan x$, we know that all of the coefficients after the first are negative.

$\bf{Added:}$ I was lead to this question in trying to prove that in the Maclaurin [expansion](https://TaylorSeries%5B%20%20x%5E2/(1%20-%20x%20Cot%5Bx%5D)%20+%203/5%20%20(1-x%20Cot%5Bx%5D)-2%20,%20%7Bx,%200,%2030%7D%5D) of $ \frac{x^2}{1 - x \cot x} + \frac{3}{5} ( 1 - x \cot x) - 2 $ all of the coefficients are positive. Since we have formulas for the expansion of the second term, we are interested in explicit formulas for the expansion of the first term.

$\bf{Added:}$ We have the continued fraction
$$\frac{x^2}{1 - x \cot x} = 3 - \frac{x^2}{ 5 - \frac{x^2}{ 7 - \cdots} } $$
following easily from the continued fraction for $\tan x$.

Comment: Wolfram gives [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=maclaurin+expansion&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22maclaurin+expansion%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TaylorSeries%22%2C+%22taylorFunction%22%7D+-%3E%22x%5E2%2F%281-x+cot%28x%29%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22TaylorSeries%22%2C+%22taylorPoint%22%7D+-%3E%220%22) result.

Comment: @John Wayland Bales:  Thank you for your interest. Yes, I think we can calculate explicitly the coefficients up to a level-- but I wondered if there was an explicit formula like for $1- x \cot x$.

Comment: For $1 - x \cot x$ you have Bernoulli numbers in the coefficients. If you think Bernoulli numbers count as "explicit formula", then you may simply name the coefficients of $\frac{x^2}{1 - x\cot x}$: call them "orange numbers" and you get an explicit formula. The real thing is not whether a formula is explicit or not, but how many properties you can prove for these coefficients.

Comment: There was an answer to this question in Section 6 of the paper: F. T. Howard, Properties of the van der Pol numbers and polynomials, J. Reine Angew. Math., vol. 260, pp. 35--46, 1973; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1973.260.35.

Comment: @WhatsUp At the site https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4254493, there are many “explicit” formulas for the Bernoulli numbers. I am sure that the Bernoulli numbers can be expressed by many closed-form expressions.

Comment: There are more new results related to this question in the newly-published paper: Zhen-Ying Sun, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, Determinantal expressions, identities, concavity, Maclaurin power series expansions for van der Pol numbers, Bernoulli numbers, and cotangent, Axioms 12 (2023), no. 7, Article 665, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/axioms12070665.

Comment: @qifeng618: Amazing results, it all seems so very interesting! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Bessel functions, we find
\begin{align*}
\frac{{x^3 }}{{1 - x\cot x}} & = 3 - x\frac{{J_{5/2} (x)}}{{J_{3/2} (x)}} = \frac{3}{2} + x\frac{{J'_{3/2} (x)}}{{J_{3/2} (x)}} = 3 - 2x^2 \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{1 - (x/j_{3/2,k}^2 )^2 }}} 
\\ & = 3 - 2x^2 \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{j_{3/2,k}^{2n} }}x^{2n} } }  = 3 - 2x^2 \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{j_{3/2,k}^{2n} }}} } \right)x^{2n} } \\& = 3 - 2x^2 \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\sigma _{2n} \!\left( \tfrac{3}{2} \right)x^{2n} }, 
\end{align*}
where $j_{3/2,k}$ denotes the $k$th positive zero of $J_{3/2}$ and $\sigma_n$ is the Rayleigh function of order $n$. If $n\geq 1$, we can write
$$
\sigma _{2n} \!\left( {\tfrac{3}{2}} \right) = ( - 1)^{n - 1} 3 \cdot 2^{2n - 1} \frac{{V_{2n} }}{{(2n)!}},
$$
where $V_n$ is the $n$th van der Pol number. See [this](https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1973.260.35) paper for properties of these numbers, including recurrence relations. In particular, your generating function is equation $(d)$ in Section $1$.

Comment: Thank you!  Very informative.  Great!

Comment: In Section 6 of the paper "F. T. Howard, Properties of the van der Pol numbers and polynomials, J. Reine Angew. Math., vol. 260, pp. 35--46, 1973; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1973.260.35", the following series expansion was established:
\begin{equation}\label{Howard-COT-Ser-1973}
\frac{z^2}{1-z\cot z}=3-\frac{z^2}{5}+3\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^k2^{2k}V_{2k}\frac{z^{2k}}{(2k)!},
\end{equation}
where $V_{2k}$ denotes the van der Pol numbers.

Comment: @qifeng618 Isn't it exactly what I am citing in my answer?

Comment: @Gary Did you mention “Section 6”? I think you didn’t. Is your answer same to the proof in “Section 6”? Not the same, I think. I am misled by your answer.

Comment: @qifeng618 I came up with the answer myself and then found the paper by Howard. I am citing it so that people can learn more properties of these coefficients if they are interested. I wonder why this answer has been downvoted.

Comment: @Gary Several best answers given by me were also downvoted: Not everybody is an expert at the problem and its answers. As you wrote, your answer is slightly different from the one in “Section 6” of Howard’s paper. Due to your mention of Howard’s paper, I read and benefitted from the paper by Howard once again, thanks Gary.

Comment: This answer and related comments are included in the paper: Zhen-Ying Sun, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, Determinantal expressions, identities, concavity, Maclaurin power series expansions for van der Pol numbers, Bernoulli numbers, and cotangent, Axioms vol. 12 (2023), no. 7, Article 665, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/axioms12070665.